# How to continuously draw boundary boxes on PDF & get it's coordinates without clearing PDF contents?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I'm working on a project where we deal with PDF documents, both text embedded & one made with collating scanned images.
I'm suppose to develop a functionality that allows user to draw boundary boxes on the PDF document to mark the data (field values) on it, using React JS technology. Also, the solution should provide the co-ordinates of the vertices of the boxes drawn on the PDF document.
To do so, I tried to draw continuously on canvas but it draws multiple rectangles.
I also tried to use clearreact but then it clears all document that is rendered on the canvas!!!
Is there any alternate method to draw on PDF document or
Is there anything other than canvas I can possibly use to draw continuous boxes, that will also provide me the co-ordinates of the boxes drawn on the PDF document? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!

I am using Canvas, but it is not proper solution.I expect different method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.